# Jetpack Compose Navigation: PopUpTo Screen from Screens that have same route except argument

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

navigation compose version `2.4.0-alpha06`

I have a Navigation Drawer using `Scaffold` and part of the items are dynamically generated by ViewModel.

Example items are

- Home
- A
- B
- C
  ...
- Settings

where A, B, C, ... all share same `Screen` called `Category`, with just different arguments passed (e.g. Category/A, Category/B).

Inside my `Scaffold`

```kotlin
...

val items = viewModel.getDrawerItems()
// This gives something like 
// ["Home", "Category/A", "Category/B", "Category/C", ..., "Settings"] 
// where each String represents "route"

...

val backstackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentScreen = Screen.fromRoute(
    backstackEntry.value?.destination?.route
)
Log.d("Drawer", "currentScreen: $currentScreen")

items.forEach { item ->
    DrawerItem(
        item = item, 
        isSelected = currentScreen.name == item.route, 
        onItemClick = {
            Log.d("Drawer", "destinationRoute: ${item.route}")
            navController.navigate(item.route)
            scope.launch {
                scaffoldState.drawerState.close()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

This code works pretty well, except when I visit Home screen, I want to clear all backstack upto Home not inclusive.

I've tried adding `NavOptionsBuilder`

```kotlin
...

navController.navigate(item.route) {
    popUpTo(currentScreen.name) {
        inclusive = true
        saveState = true
    }
}
...
```

However, this doesn't work because `currentScreen.name` will give something like `Category/{title}` and popUpTo only tries to look up exact match from the backstack, so it doesn't pop anything.

**Is there real compose-navigation way to solve this? or should I save the last "title" somewhere in ViewModel and use it?**

[This tutorial from Google](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#0) has similar structure, but it just stacks screens so going back from screen A -> B -> A and clicking back will just go back to B -> A, which is not ideal behavior for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're specifying `popUpTo` you should pass same item you're navigating to in this case:

```
navController.navigate(item.route) {
    popUpTo(item.route) {
        inclusive = true
    }
}
```

Also not sure if you need to specify `saveState` in this case, it's up to you:

> Whether the back stack and the state of all destinations between the current destination and the `NavOptionsBuilder.popUpTo` ID should be saved for later restoration via `NavOptionsBuilder.restoreState` or the restoreState attribute using the same `NavOptionsBuilder.popUpTo` ID (note: this matching ID is true whether inclusive is true or false).

Comment: Not using `saveState` fixed the issue :), right now I only have simple button and a text, but later I want to add `LazyColumn` for list of items. If I set `saveState = false` wouldn't it forget all the state and scroll positions will be reset as it recomposes? Thank you!

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh `saveState = false` discards views you're removing from backstack, for those scroll position will be lost. Your current view won't lost anything. Does it work without replacing `popUpTo` destination?

Comment: I've made another answer below to include code of how I was able to achieve what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: it only works if you want to remove only previous screen from the backstack, what about if I want to remove 2 last screens from the stack before opening the 3 one?  We have to set the screen id as we can with navigation component and graph.xml. Basically if I didn't reach 3 then I have to keep last 2 screens and clear them from stack only if I enter 3 screen

Answer (score 9):

You can make an extension function to serve the **popUpTo** functionality at all places.

```
fun NavHostController.navigateWithPopUp(
    toRoute: String,  // route name where you want to navigate
    fromRoute: String // route you want from popUpTo.
) {
    this.navigate(toRoute) {
        popUpTo(fromRoute) {
            inclusive = true // It can be changed to false if you
                             // want to keep your fromRoute exclusive
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
navController.navigateWithPopUp(Screen.Home.name, Screen.Login.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Philip Dukhov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901279/3690442), I was able to achieve what I wanted.

```kotlin
...

navController.navigate(item.route) {
    // keep backstack until user goes to Home
    if (item.route == Screen.Home.name) {
        popUpTo(item.route) {
            inclusive = true
            saveState = true
        }
    } else {
        // only restoreState for non-home screens
        restoreState = true
    }
...
```

Unfortunately, if I add `launchSingleTop = true`, Screen with different argument is not recomposed for some reason, but that's probably another topic.

Comment: Okay. As I'm looking at this more, I realize how weird this is. so that `popUpTo(item.route)` is really equivalent to `popUpTo(Screen.Home.name)`. I realized it navigates to Home screen, and (should) immediately pops it up to its own, because of `inclusive = true`? Then why do I still have Home?